# Altering a Cassandra UDT column

Tags: cassandra, user-defined-types, alter

I have a Cassandra UDT column that has about 10 attributes and now we are planning to add 3 more attributes to it. I am wondering if it would behave well if I alter the UDT type in the higher environments which has very large volume of data.

Answer (score 1):

Altering UDT is same as altering table, except that you cannot remove an existing UDT unless you drop all the depended tables. Also you can't alter type of a column. Below is the query how you could add new udt columnd.

```
alter TYPE commentmetadata ADD columnname <type>;
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be safe. 
Just few precautions:

1. Don't run in mixed version Cassandra cluster.
2. Don't try to do same schema change concurrently from multiple client ( driver)

Answer (score 0):

Additional pointers when you alter your table with UDT collections data type:

- Never insert more than 2 billion items in a collection, as only that number can be queried.
- The maximum number of keys for a map collection is 65,535.
- The maximum size of an item in a list or a map collection is 2GB.
- The maximum size of an item in a set collection is 65,535 bytes.
- Keep collections small to prevent delays during querying.
- Collections cannot be "sliced"; Cassandra reads a collection in its entirety, impacting performance.

Click [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.3/cql/cql_using/useCollections.html)  for more information.

[Alex Ott] MAP & LIST limits are version dependent.
65,535 bytes are supported by v3.0+ while lower versions are limited to 64,000 bytes. Fix version [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10374).

Comment: sorry, but what is the point of answer? The question is about UDT, not collections... Also, limits are version dependent, and the item "The maximum size of an item in a set collection is 65,535 bytes." isn't correct in 2020th (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10374) and it's just a error in documentation...